# snakemake - accessing config variables from cluster submission wrapper

Tags: python, cluster-computing, hpc, snakemake, pbs

I am using a cluster submission wrapper script with `snakemake --cluster "python qsub_script.py"`. I need to pass a global variable, taken from the `config['someVar']`. This should be applied to all rules. I could add it to the `params` of each rule, and then access it using `job_properties['params']['someVar']`, but this is probably not the best solution. Is there a way to access `config` from the submission wrapper? Simply using `config['someVar']` gives me a `NameError`.

If that's not possible, can you suggest an alternative? I suspect using profiles could be helpful, but couldn't figure out how this interacts with the submission wrapper.

Comment: *The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem statement is a bit broad, so the solution below might not be the most optimal, but it should achieve what you are looking for. Specifically, the code below allows modifying every rule in the workflow.

Here's a reproducible demo:

```py
rule all:
    input:
        "a.txt",
        "b.txt",


rule a:
    output:
        "a.txt",
    shell:
        """
        echo {params.val} > {output}
        """


rule b:
    output:
        "b.txt",
    shell:
        """
        echo {params.val} > {output}
        """

# this allows iteration across every rule using python syntax
# so complex business logic can be implemented
for n, r in enumerate(workflow.rules):
    r.set_params(val=n)
```

For your specific use-case, the last chunk of code could look like this:

```py
for r in workflow.rules:
    r.set_params(someVar=config["someVar"])
```

Where the `config` dictionary is defined within the workflow using `configfile`:

```py
configfile: "config.yaml"
```

Comment: Thank you! Just out of curiosity: is this (say the `workflow` object) documented anywhere? I searched quite a lot, but was unable to find anything useful in the snakemake documentation.

Comment: Nope, this is not explicitly documented AFAIK.