# How to access Snakemake parameters inside Snakefile?

Tags: python, snakemake

I'm trying to figure out how to access the Snakemake parameters inside my Snakefile, e.g. the set target rule (either specified by user or first defined rule). I was able to find some settings in the environment using `dir()`, but not the target rule. Is that even accessible?

**EDIT**: I would like to print an overview of the most important parameters at the beginning of the run, including the user ID, path to config file, and also the target rule (since our workflow has multiple endpoints/target rules, I find it useful to have it logged somewhere).

After some more digging, I found the `workflow` object that contains some useful information, however the `first_rule` is set to `None`. I would've expected that property to be set to the target rule but perhaps I just haven't understood the purpose of it yet, and/or no information should be extracted from the `workflow` object.

I know that I can use the `--report` feature to get a lot of information - and we do use it - but would like to be independent from it.

Thank you!

Comment: This should be possible, but could you elaborate a bit on the use case? Or perhaps provide a more thorough example?

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev Thank you for your comment! In the original post I expanded my motivation and what I'm trying to accomplish. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the updated question it does seem like `workflow` could be useful. Specifically, one option is to iterate over all the rules in a workflow (see [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71531139/10693596)), extracting information of interest during the iterations. Specifically for the target rule information, running `snakemake -j 1` on the following Snakefile seems to output the required information:

```py
rule all:
    input:
        "a.txt",
        "b.txt",


rule a:
    output:
        "a.txt",
    shell:
        """
        echo "a" > {output}
        """


rule b:
    output:
        "b.txt",
    default_target: True,
    shell:
        """
        echo "b" > {output}
        """

print(workflow.default_target)
# will print b
```

One caution in terms of `printing`, if you are doing cluster submission or your rules have shell commands that are sensitive to incoming data, it might be better to log information into a file vs. printing to stdout. At least I had experience with some non-obvious bugs that eventually could be traced to me printing in the Snakefile.

Update: this is a hack for an edge case, but in case one is interested in modifying dynamically the `default_target`, it might be possible to do something like below (this is only pseudocode, not tested):

```py
# assume that config contains the name of the desired target rule
default_target = config["default_target"]

for n, r in enumerate(workflow.rules):
    if r.name == default_target:
        r.default_target = True
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the answer. The `default_target` property was probably added in a later version (later than the one I'm using) since it doesn't exist in my `workflow` object. I'll try updating Snakemake and check what information I can extract then. One question though: Would the `default_target` property still point to rule `b` if the workflow was launched with `snakemake a -j 1` (specifically using rule a as target)?

Comment: `snakemake a -j 1` will also print `b`, since that is the `default_target` for the workflow, at least in version `7.8.1`.

Comment: Sure, I updated the answer with one possible hack (though not 100% sure it will work).